reconnecting in google Colab
I am using from python 3.8 in google colab. After installing the transformer, the following warning is received, And after a few minutes the connection is disconnected.
How can I prevent this from happening?
WARNING: The following packages were previously imported in this runtime: [cycler,kiwisolver,six] You must restart the runtime in order to use newly installed versions. Restarting will lose all runtime state, including local variables.


Can you add what are you trying to install and do because a simple import method wouldn't affect colab.

Yes, in the code, the transformer is imported

Please add specifically which codepiece or import is failing. Simply stating transformer is imported is not going to help in this issue.

I think this error is related to the installation of a package and has nothing to do with the code.
Because this code used to run well, this warning is recently received

Hello! Can you edit the post to add the contents of the cell (Python or Linux commands) which emitted this message?
